# Running multiple ROS process in a Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, ros

I want to create a bash script which installs all required software to run a docker, create a new image and then runs, in a container, all required processes. My bash script looks like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containered.io
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker


docker pull ros:indigo-robot
docker build -t myimage .
docker run --name myimage-cont -dit myimage
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ros:indigo-robot

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    git \ 
    ros-indigo-ardrone-autonomy
```

I am new to Docker and do not know best practices, but what I need to achieve is running 3 different process at the same time.
- roscore
- rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver
- rostopic pub ardrone/takeoff std_msgs/Empty "{}" --once

I was able to achieve it 'manually' by opening 3 terminals and executing `docker exec myimage-cont...` commands. However, what I need it is make it automatically run by the code once I execute my bash script. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Best practice is almost universally to `docker run` three separate containers off the same image, or to use an orchestration tool like Docker Compose to do that for you.

Comment: @DavidMaze Would it still work, even though these processes cooperate with each other- one cannot run if the other doesn't?

Comment: @DavidMaze in ROS documentation there is a special page about it http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Compose so I believe this is the right way to go. Thank you.